# Doctrine symfony - query with view and left join

Tags: join, symfony1, doctrine

I want to make sth like this query using doctrine in symfony.

```sql
SELECT * FROM view_of_model1 LEFT JOIN model2 ON model1.id = model2.model1_id
```

With the raw sql is no problem but I need to have connection with models of `model1` and `model2`. `view_of_model1` is a perspective which as same fields as model1 table.

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT:
I have a `table1`

```
id | col_datetime1 | col_datetime2 | some_col
---------------------------------------------
```

And I want to sort it by datetime cols. If `some_col = true` i want to sort by `col_datetime1` and if `some_col = false` I want to sort by `col_datetime2`. Additionally I want to join an another table (e.g. `table2`) `on table1.id = table2.table1_id`. It can be done by subqueries in `from` section connected with `UNION`. It can also be done by creating a view. But how to map it to symfony models?

EDIT2:
NativeQuery will help?

Comment: Why don't you query the tables instead of the views? You're just complicating things. And views aren't supposed to be used from the application's perspective in first place.

Comment: I want to use perspective because it has two subquery conected with union so I thought it will be more simple to make it as view.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that views are just complications with no added value in your case, since all what you want is making things easier.

If you want to make it simpler to get the data you want, without writing the joins every time, create a method in the Table class that does the query, as shown [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/06#chapter_06_refactoring).
This is a good practice even if you won't use that method many times, because database queries aren't supposed to be written in the controllers.

Example:

```
class MyTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function getMyStuff($value)
  {
    return $this->createQuery('m')
      ->where('m.my_column = ?', $value)
      ->execute();
  }
}
```